# How to add a new post on Opencart forum?

Tags: opencart, forums

I have an account at **opencart** forum https://forum.opencart.com/ and I have a few things to ask regarding **opencart**, but I don't get to know how to add a new post on this forum, there is no option showing in my account to add a new post. I have searched but could not find anything. Can anybody tell me about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Login.

2.choose where to post your new post..

- like General,OpenCart 2.0 Support etc.
- then choose and click on that type of support...

3.click on general support.

4.you can see the

> new topic

on left click and post your new post to forum.

If any doubt  ask me i will help you.hope this work for you.